# The file is being properly opened & closed then why the new line character '\n' not working in Python while writing or appending file content?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning Python and using Jupyter to write Python code. I am working on File Handling currently.

My Code goes like this:

```
file = open(r"C:\USERS\PRAGA\DESKTOP\TestFile.txt",'w')
file.write("I can do it")
file.close()
file = open(r"C:\USERS\PRAGA\DESKTOP\TestFile.txt",'a')
file.write("\nBelieve in yourself. Yes, you can do it.")
file = open(r"C:\USERS\PRAGA\DESKTOP\TestFile.txt",'r')
Last_content = file.read()
Last_content
```

The final answer is

```
I can do it\nBelieve in yourself. Yes, you can do it.
```

Expected answer:

```
I can do it
Believe in yourself. Yes, you can do it.
```

When I opened the text file, the expected answer is coming but but not getting displayed in the editor.

Why the newline character is not working?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar It shouldn't interrupt the special character from being displayed correctly when printing.

Comment: Please see the edit. This is the exact reason for this "problem".

Comment: @mr_mo, you're right. My explanation was wrong (removing the comment), but the dupe has the same problem which is explained in the first answer.

Comment: No. That didn't resolve my issue but print did. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

Look at the following example:

[image]

Clearly, we get the desired output.
However, in your code you simply do `Last_content` in the last line, which redirects the content to the notebook, which eventually displays it as a text string. When jupyter handles the text to `display` it on screen, it escapes special characters to avoid errors in framework. Hence, you get your problem. (Pointed out by @SergiyKolesnikov, it is done by internal representation)

**EDIT2**: Plase see complete screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks mr_mo. "print" solved my issue.

Comment: @Pragati No problem, please vote and mark as answered.